# shell_exec sed -i write file

Tags: php, linux, apache

I have a very simple script `run.php`

```
<?php
shell_exec('/var/www/html/insert.sh');
?>
```

insert.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
sed -i '/blah/ r file1.txt' config.xml
```

I am getting following error on apache logs:

```
sed: couldn't open temporary file ./sedV5qH6N: Permission denied
sed: couldn't open temporary file ./sedBS3zO6: Permission denied
sed: couldn't open temporary file ./sedR4Nw3O: Permission denied
```

Even i gave it full permission with `apache` owner. How can I correct the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to be able to edit afile in place, sed needs the right to create a temporary file in the same directory as the file. Clearly, your script does not have the right to write in the given directory.

Comment: Can i tell `sed` use different directory for temporary work? like `/tmp`

Comment: I don't think so if you want to use the -i (in place) option, but you could do something like "sed '/blah/ r file1.txt' config.xml > /tmp/config.xml && mv /tmp/config.xml config.xml". Note that there is an obvious race condition in that case.